# Default Behavior for OnBackPressedCallback in Activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to implement the [OnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) detailed in Navigation Components in my app. The documentation is very clear on how to add this custom behavior in fragments, and works quite well. After reading the linked documentation, it states that you should avoid overriding `onBackPressed` in your activity. My current `onBackPressed` method looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
      drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (shouldOverrideBackPressed()) {
      navigationController.popBackStack(R.id.main_fragment, false);
    } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The last line `super.onBackPressed();` is what I'm not clear about. How do I retain the default behavior for the back button in an activity while implementing the `OnBackPressedCallback`? This is my current implementation:

```
getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
  @Override
  public void handleOnBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
      drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (shouldOverrideBackPressed()) {
      navigationController.popBackStack(R.id.main_fragment, false);
    } else {
      setEnabled(false);
      MainActivity.this.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
});
```

If I don't include the `setEnabled(false);` line, then I get a Stack Overflow error, which makes sense. But surely there is a more elegant way to provide default behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting all of that logic in one `OnBackPressedCallback`. Instead, each case should be its **own** callback that is only enabled when it is the one that should be handling the back pressed.

You should **not** be calling `onBackPressed()`, etc in `handleOnBackPressed()`. An important part of the contract is that when you get a callback to `handleOnBackPressed()`, you must handle the back pressed button there. That's precisely why you have control over exactly when the callback is enabled or not.

This means you should create one `OnBackPressedCallback` for your override behavior (although you should probably not being doing that with Navigation anyways) and another for the `DrawerLayout` that uses a [`DrawerListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) for enabling and disabling the callback:

```
OnBackPressedDispatcher dispatcher = getOnBackPressedDispatcher();

final OnBackPressedCallback overrideCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(false) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        navigationController.popBackStack(R.id.main_fragment, false);
    }
};
// Whenever your `shouldOverrideBackPressed()` changes, you need to
// call setEnabled(true) or setEnabled(false) so that callback
// is only called exactly when it needs to handle the back button

// Add this one first since they are called in reverse order
dispatcher.addCallback(this, overrideCallback);

// Now set up the DrawerLayout's callback
final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_drawer_layout);
final OnBackPressedCallback drawerCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
        drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        // Unconditionally close the drawer when it is open
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
};
// Now add a listener so that this callback is only
// enabled when the drawer is open
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        // Assume you only have one drawer
        drawerCallback.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        // Assume you only have one drawer
        drawerCallback.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
// Add it last so that it gets called before the overrideCallback
dispatcher.addCallback(this, drawerCallback);
```

Of course, if you're overriding things at the Activity level, there's no downside to keeping your logic in `onBackPressed()` - as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#activity_onbackpressed), any callbacks registered from Fragments, etc. will correctly be called when you call `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response Ian! This is a great explanation. It would be great to see the official documentation updated with more detail like this!

Comment: Enabling/disabling callbacks declaratively looks nice, but sometimes the inability to "delegate to default/next" is very inconvenient.

For example with `WebView`: `if (webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack() else ???`

Or with custom navigation: `if (!viewModel.goBack()) ???`. `viewModel` here should control navigation completely, except exiting the app. In this specific case we could call `finish()`, but [it's not recommended](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#back-press).

In these cases `return false`, as e.g. with touch events, might be better.

Comment: @gmk57 - you might take a look at the [Predictive Back codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/handling-gesture-back-navigation#5) linked from the [Predictive Back guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture) which actually uses WebView as the example for how to properly use `setEnabled` without using `canGoBack()` at all. The whole point of the ahead of time model (and the animations it allows) is that you have to update your state as it changes, you can't wait until after the gesture is fully committed.

Comment: This makes sense if you have a single condition and it is in the same code level that adds the dispatcher. But the condition can be consisted of any values somewhere. Letting the details that are spread around the app to know they should call something to update the enable state of the back callback? Even if the details would call abstract callback, putting this everywhere where the relevant values are modified? That would be bug prone, breaks encapsulation, messy, and against reasonable software design. To me it makes much more sense that isEnabled() should have been a function to override.

Comment: P.S. and the code that is changing values is not always open for changes like listening.

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari - the only place that should be adding a single responsibility `OnBackPressedCallback` is the layer that owns that exact condition used to enable or disable the callback and the exact layer that manages the Predictive Back gesture animation for tied to that condition. If you find yourself doing something different, then you've either broken the single responsibility of a callback or put it at the wrong layer. That's why you can put it at any layer (not only at the activity layer) and why you can have multiple, single responsibility callbacks for different cases.

Comment: @ianhanniballake What will be the trigger? When will I disable/enable this callback? In your example you used drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(). That is specific to components that have something like that. Of course there can be solutions that have their own cons. Like a check every few milliseconds. But that is instead of a simple condition.
That is why it looks to me that isEnabled() should have been a function to override. Because then the trigger is the system, when it need to know.

Comment: @ianhanniballake P.S. What is single responsibility in practice? Is "if ((A && B && C) || D)" a single responsibility? Maybe only the and's. And then I should hope that all of them have listeners?

Comment: but `onBackPressed` is deprecated