# Simplest onBackPressed logic to be replaced using the OnBackPressedDispatcher interface

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

So, our project is compiling against & targeting `Android SDK 33` which means the `onBackPressed()` function in `Activity` is deprecated and that needs to be converted to using the `onBackPressedDispatcher`. However, I am finding it hard to convert the simplest of `onBackPressed()` logic. Basically, before the system handles the `onBackPressed()` I want to run a simple statement. Here is the piece of code.

```
  override fun onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
    super.onBackPressed()
  }
```

I understand that `onBackPressedDispatcher` callbacks are selectively enabled and disabled depending on the states like explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148783. Our case doesn't fit in that model.

In our case, I want it to be always enabled and I want the system to handle the backpress after the custom logic is run. If we enable it always, there is no way for us to call the equivalent of `super.onBackPressed()`.

Any guidance on this is appreciated.